# 2D array as parameter in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, parameters, multidimensional-array

I would like to pass a 2D array to another function. I have an example of my code that I have all in the main function. However, the assignment requires that we split the code into a total of three functions, the main, adjmatrix, and adjlist functions.

**All in the main function**

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
   ifstream in;

   char infile[40];
   int c, u, v;

   cout << "Please enter the input data file name(NO SPACES): ";
   cin >> infile;

   in.open(infile);
   while(in.fail()) {
      cout << "Please enter a CORRECT input data file name(NO SPACES): ";
      cin >> infile;
      in.open(infile);
   }

   //adj matrix

   cout << "Adjacency Matrix" << endl;
   in >> c;
   int array[c][c];
   for(int i=0; i<c; i++) {
      for(int j=0; j<c; j++) {
         array[i][j] = 0;
      }
   }

   while(in >> u >> v) {
      array[u][v] = 1;
   }

   cout << c << endl;
   for(int i=0;i<c;i++) {
      cout << i << "   ";
      for(int j=0;j<c;j++){
         cout << array[i][j] << " ";
      }
      cout << endl;
   }
   cout << endl;

   //adj list

   cout << "Adjacency List" << endl;
   cout << c << endl;
   for(int i=0;i<c;i++) {
      cout << i  << " --> ";
      for(int j=0;j<c;j++) {
         if(array[i][j] == 1) {
            cout << j << " ";
         }
      }
      cout << endl;
   }

   in.close();

   return 0;
}
```

This program outputs an adjacency matrix and adjacency list from the following input file

```
9
2 8
0 6
8 5
2 4
3 1
2 3
4 1
6 1
2 6
7 5
1 7
```

The following is the output

```
Adjacency Matrix
9
0   0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
1   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
2   0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1
3   0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
4   0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
5   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
6   0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
7   0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
8   0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0

Adjacency List
9
0 --> 6
1 --> 7
2 --> 3 4 6 8
3 --> 1
4 --> 1
5 -->
6 --> 1
7 --> 5
8 --> 5
```

I read somewhere that passing a 2D array requires the second dimension to be entered. I also read something about it having to be a global constant? So I may have gotten a little crazy and went off on the crazy path on trying some things so please excuse some of the stupidity. The problem I think I am having is the actual array size comes from the file so I dont really understand where to go for declaring an array's second dimension with an actual value when *int c* is initialized to the first value in the input file. The following is my failed attempt at passing a 2D array. Enjoy:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;

const int c;

void adjmatrix(istream &in, int array[][c]);

int main(void)
{
   ifstream in;

   char infile[40];

   cout << "Please enter the input data file name(NO SPACES): ";
   cin >> infile;

   in.open(infile);
   while(in.fail()) {
      cout << "Please enter a CORRECT input data file name(NO SPACES): ";
      cin >> infile;
      in.open(infile);
   }

   in >> c;
   int array[c][c];

   adjmatrix(in, array);

   in.close();

   return 0;
}

void adjmatrix(istream &in, int array[][c])
{
   int u,v;
   for(int i=0; i<c; i++) {
      for(int j=0; j<c; j++) {
         array[i][j] = 0;
      }
   }

   while(in >> u >> v) {
      array[u][v] = 1;
   }

   cout << c << endl;

   for(int i=0; i<c; i++) {
      cout << i << "   ";
      for(int j=0; j<c; j++) {
         cout << array[i][j] << " ";
      }
      cout << endl;
   }
   cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: `in >> c; int array[c][c];`  This is not standard C++.  You must declare array sizes with a compile-time expression.  Use `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` or build one up starting from an `int**` if for some reason you can't use `vector`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can allocate the array dynamically instead of statically defining it.

```
int i;
int **array;

in >> c;
array = new int*[c];

for(i=0;i<c;i++)
   array[i] = new int[c];

 adjmatrix(in, array,c);
```

The declaration of the function adjmatrix will be `adjmatrix(istream &in, int **array,int c);`

Comment: Don't forget `delete[]`

Answer (score 0):

Following may help:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

void print_adjacency_matrix(const std::vector<std::vector<int>>& mat)
{
    std::cout << "Adjacency Matrix" << std::endl;

    std::cout << mat.size() << std::endl;
    for(std::size_t i = 0; i != mat.size(); ++i) {
        std::cout << i << "   ";
        for(auto e : mat[i]) {
            std::cout << e << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

void print_adjacency_list(const std::vector<std::vector<int>>& mat)
{
    std::cout << "Adjacency List" << std::endl;
    std::cout << mat.size() << std::endl;
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i != mat.size(); ++i) {
        std::cout << i << " --> ";
        for(auto e : mat[i]) {
            if (e == 1) {
                std::cout << e << " ";
            }
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::ifstream in;
    std::string infile;

    std::cout << "Please enter the input data file name(NO SPACES): ";
    std::cin >> infile;

    in.open(infile);
    while(in.fail()) {
        std::cout << "Please enter a CORRECT input data file name(NO SPACES): ";
        std::cin >> infile;
        in.open(infile);
    }

    int c;
    in >> c;
    std::vector<std::vector<int> > array(c, std::vector<int>(c));

    int u, v;
    while(in >> u >> v) {
        array[u][v] = 1;
    }
    in.close();

    print_adjacency_matrix(array);
    print_adjacency_list(array);

    return 0;
}
```